# libfcl-0.5-dev cant resolve depends

Tags: ros, moveit, source, fcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Building moveit from source on a debian jessie install on a hP Xeon Proliant server.

```
rosdep 
 Unable to locate package libfcl-0.5-dev
 Couldn't find any package by regex 'libfcl-0.5.dev'
```

my last issue was because my `sources.list` was messed, up and I did a `apt-get update` and solve it, if this has any bearing....

Thanks for all the assistance.

---

Edit:

```
rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install libfcl-0.5-dev]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfcl-0.5-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libfcl-0.5-dev'
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install libfcl-0.5-dev] failed
```

Indigo Branch

I think the stray period was my fingers....sorry for the confusion..... How do I verify amd64 or i386? If I remember correctly, i386.

---

Edit: Here is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hpdeb 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) i686 GNU/Linux
```

and:

```
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd
```

perviosly I was running on a virtual machine and I switched to actual hardware to overcome some of the challenges with moveit and the virtMach.

The system I have available for this is an HP Proliant DL360 Gen 3 with 1 Xeon 2.4GHz processor( which I believe is 2 cores and 2Gb ram only, Ubuntu  16 lts , I could not solve the video issues to this latemodel, so I shifted to Debian. I was not sure of how well this setup would work with Kinetic so I tried to play it safe, down on the earlier versions of code base, I would love to be able to run kinetic and moveit, Just am unaware if my hardware with support it. Since it looks like I have to reinstall everything, please give me your suggestions.

Downloading the AMD64 version of Debian now....

AWE CRAP.......(?)

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 2
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 2.40GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               2399.360
BogoMIPS:              4798.91
```

just verified... 32 bit only....crappp.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254853/libfcl-0.5-dev-cant-resolve-depends/) by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Which branch of the `moveit` repository are you trying to build?

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-16**:
Indigo Branch... ROS already installed and is functioning(WOW... AMAZING)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
I notice there is a dot in the package regex after the `5` (`libfcl-0.5.dev`), can you copy-paste some more context (ie: more lines of console output) into your question? I'm wondering where that dot is coming from.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Also: is that output from `apt-get` or `rosdep`? I expect `rosdep` to say something like "can't resolve X etc etc", not "Unable to locate packge ..".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Finally; is this an `i386` system, or `amd64`? I see builds for `amd64` and `arm64` [here](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fcl/) but not for `i386`, hence my question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Could you please edit your question with updates? There is not enough space in the comment boxes for console command output. Use the *edit* link/button below your question text for that. Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
What is the output of `uname -a` and `file /sbin/init`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
I'm sorry you are having so much trouble getting things to install/work btw. You appear to just choose some very unlucky combinations of hw/sw for your setups. Building pkgs for all combinations of platforms/archs/OS/distributions is just not feasible.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:\

> Downloading the AMD64 version of Debian now....

I would first make sure you have a 64bit CPU. Do something like `lscpu` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and check what the precise model of CPU you have is.

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-16**:
I have had some successes to sustain me along my path. I was able, with your help to get rosserial running on a nextthing chip that is publishing data  to a networked ROSMASTER, So I know it works.... Just hoping to get to the next level with the move it package.
Thank you for your continued support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> $ uname -a
> ```

```
Linux hpdeb 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) i686 GNU/Linux
```

That's a 32bit install of Debian Jessie. Unfortunately, I don't see any 32bit packages for `libfcl-0.5-dev` on the [package repository](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fcl/) for Jessie (nor in the *shadow* repository). That could explain why `apt-get` can't find it.

That package is built at [build.osrfoundation.org/job/fcl0.5-pkg_builder-master-generic](http://build.osrfoundation.org/job/fcl0.5-pkg_builder-master-generic/), and I don't see an `i386` version there either.

Three options:

1. ask OSRF to build an `i386` version for Jessie (but I don't think that is going to happen, seeing as Jessie is only supported on `amd64` and `arm64`)
2. build `libfcl-dev` from source: see the *Flexible Collision Library (FCL)* section of [Building Common MoveIt! Dependencies from Source in Catkin](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/dependencies/index.html#flexible-collision-library-fcl)
3. install the `amd64` version of Debian Jessie (note that Jessie binaries are only built for ROS Kinetic, but that does include MoveIt ([here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_dj.html?q=moveit)), so you wouldn't have to build it from sources)

Did you have a specific reason to install 32bit Jessie (hw support fi)?

---

Edit: if you'd like `rosdep` to continue installing things that it can find for your platform, add the `-r` option to the command line. At the end it should print a summary of things it couldn't install.

---

Edit2:

> ```
> Architecture:          i686
> ```

Seeing as you don't have a 64bit CPU, you could probably install a 32bit Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) and install Indigo on that. Most of the stuff is still being built for it, but expect that to become less over time (newer ROS versions won't be build on the farm for `i386` anymore). And just to make sure: MoveIt is being built for 32bit Trusty ([here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=moveit)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-16**:
Please look at this for me.....
http://answers.ros.org/question/254874/starting-overabout-to-sacrifice-a-good-laptop-to-my-causeneed-incantations-i-mean-advice/